# Sort mongo results by string enum value

Tags: mongodb, sorting, enums

Is there any way to sort documents from MongoDB based on an enumeration of string values?

What I'm trying to achieve is simply sorting log message objects based on a severity.  So the documents look like:

```
{message: 'An error', severity: 'error'}
{message: 'A warning', severity: 'warning'}
{message: 'Informational message', severity: 'info'}
```

And I'd like the results sorted by the logical severity (e.g. error->warning->info) rather than alphabetical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this not what you want but you can use code-value based system on that:

```
{message: 'An error', code : 0, severity: 'error'}
{message: 'A warning', code : 1, severity: 'warning'}
{message: 'Informational message', code : 2, severity: 'info'}
```

then sort by code.

Comment: Also if you are setting a limit on the query you won't necessarily get the records needed to sort in code